# what method that is called when showing video preview in UIImagepickercontroller delegate in iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

hello all I am working an app that automatically records a video. its does not showing preview of a video since I hidden the Cameracontrols  . I want to know the method that calling the preview view..
Could anyone help me..
Thanks

**Update**

```
UIImagePickerController *vpicker; // in .h 

// place the below  code whr u want to satrt video 
vpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
vpicker.delegate=self;
vpicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
vpicker.mediaTypes=[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
vpicker.showsCameraControls=NO;
vpicker.cameraCaptureMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
BOOL test=[vpicker startVideoCapture];
NSLog(@"test value %d",test);
if(test)
{ 
  NSLog(@"vedio started");
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(stop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; 
 }
 else 
 {
   NSLog(@"sorry vedio not started to stop it ...");
 }


// in stop method 
[vpicker stopVideoCapture];
vpicker.showsCameraControls=YES;
```

Comment: Did you find an answer, how the preview is pushed?

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController is use to show video, not UIImagePickerViewController

Comment: yes but when we record something without userinteraction only it shows the preview of video with the options of (usethis and discard) .what is the method that push this view automatically

Comment: after finish recording you give your file path in URL and play that URL in MPMoviePlayerController.